# wp_insert_post memory leak - suspending cache no effect

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running a script that loops through results from an XML file and inserts posts into WP in 3 translations (using WPML functions).

The script is leaking memory badly exactly where wp_insert_post runs e.g:

```
--------------     POSTS IS NEW WE ARE GOING TO INSERT !!! --------------

Before post_inserts: 50 mb
after en insert: 54 mb
after es insert: 54 mb
after de insert: 56 mb

--------------     POSTS IS NEW WE ARE GOING TO INSERT !!! --------------

Before post_inserts: 56 mb
after en insert: 56 mb
after es insert: 56 mb
after de insert: 60 mb

--------------     POSTS IS NEW WE ARE GOING TO INSERT !!! --------------

Before post_inserts: 60 mb
after en insert: 62 mb
after es insert: 62 mb
after de insert: 64 mb

--------------     POSTS IS NEW WE ARE GOING TO INSERT !!! --------------

Before post_inserts: 64 mb
after en insert: 66 mb
after es insert: 68 mb
after de insert: 68 mb
```

...this continues until within minutes I'm over 200mb memory usage. I've read that this is an issue with wp_insert_post caching the queries so I tried `wp_suspend_cache_addition(true)` which has no effect at all.

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
$en_post = array();
$en_post = array(
    'post_title' => $property_id.': '.$titleType.' in '.$location,
    'post_date' => $listed,
    'post_content' => $enDesc,
    'post_status' => $postStatus,
    'post_author' => $userID,
    'post_type' => $postType
);

$es_post = array();
$es_post = array(
    'post_title' => $property_id.': '.$titleType.' en '.$location,
    'post_date' => $listed,
    'post_content' => $esDesc,
    'post_status' => $postStatus,
    'post_author' => $userID,
    'post_type' => $postType
);

$de_post = array();
$de_post = array(
    'post_title' => $property_id.': '.$titleType.' im '.$location,
    'post_date' => $listed,
    'post_content' => $deDesc,
    'post_status' => $postStatus,
    'post_author' => $userID,
    'post_type' => $postType
);

echo "Before post_inserts: ".convert(memory_get_usage(true))."\n\n";

wp_suspend_cache_addition(true);

$en_post_id = wp_insert_post( $en_post );
echo "after en insert: ".convert(memory_get_usage(true))."\n\n";

$es_post_id = wp_insert_post( $es_post );
echo "after es insert: ".convert(memory_get_usage(true))."\n\n";

$de_post_id = wp_insert_post( $de_post );
echo "after de insert: ".convert(memory_get_usage(true))."\n\n";

wp_suspend_cache_addition(false);

$post_ids = array();
$post_ids = array(
    'en_post' => $en_post_id,
    'es_post' => $es_post_id,
    'de_post' => $de_post_id     
);
$en_post_id = NULL;
$es_post_id = NULL;
$de_post_id = NULL;

wp_cache_flush();
```

I've also tried `wp_cache_flush()` as you can see - no dice. I've set all my variables to NULL at the end of each loop and reset arrays.

Tearing my hair out here so if anyone has an idea I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have any hooks that run on `save_post` or similar? The memory increase looks big. I've inserted thousands of posts in a loop before and while I didn't look at memory usage (wasn't a problem), it certainly didn't grow into GBs (which monitoring would've reported), which yours probably will/does.

Comment: I think you may be right. I've unhooked `save_post` from before `wp_insert_post` and the memory is stabilising with aprox 5-20mb fluctuations. I'll dive into save_post and see if I can find what exactly is causing this but I suspect its WPML related. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I was having a very similar issue, likely also related to WPML. FWIW, the specific call I made to unhook `save_post` was `remove_all_actions('save_post');`